# How to specify a generic type in a namespace by parameter value

Tags: typescript

I have a function that pulls a row from a database.

```
function row<T>(table:string, id:number):Promise<T|null>
{
   //For simplicity's sake
   return await Db(`SELECT * FROM ${table} WHERE id = ${id}`)
}
```

And also type definitions for tables in a namespace

```
export namespace Table
{
   export type office = {
      id:number
      location:string
   }

   export type person = {
      id:number
      name:string
      office:number
   }
}
```

Currently I run it with a generic type passed,

```
const person = row<Table.person>('person', 1)
```

which would give `person` with the type of Table.person but how can I make it a generic using the parameter's string value?

I was hoping something like this could be achieved, so that it will pull the type definition from the 'Table' namespace by the 'table' string parameter.

```
function row(table:string, id:number):Promise<Table[table]|null>
```

Comment: Namespaces are neither types nor values, so doing type operations with them is very limited. Is your requirement to use a namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript namespaces have limitations on the type operations we can perform. If we try type operations on a namespace, the compiler will tell us that we cannot use a namespace as a type nor a value.

Here is a workaround that manually converts the `Table` namespace into a `TableMap` type so that we can do type operations with it.

Someone with more TypeScript experience than I have might be able to improve this workaround by generating the `Tables` type instead of creating it manually.

```
namespace Table {
  export type office = {
    id: number
    location: string
  }
  export type person = {
    id: number
    name: string
    office: number
  }
}

type TableMap = {
  'office': Table.office,
  'person': Table.person,
};

type TableKey = keyof TableMap;

function row<Key extends TableKey>(table: Key, id: number): Promise<TableMap[Key] | null> {
  return null;
}

const result = row('person', 1)
```

Here it is [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=namespace%20Table%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20export%20type%20office%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20location%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20export%20type%20person%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20office%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20TableMap%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20'office'%3A%20Table.office%2C%0D%0A%20%20'person'%3A%20Table.person%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20TableKey%20%3D%20keyof%20TableMap%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20row%3CKey%20extends%20TableKey%3E(table%3A%20Key%2C%20id%3A%20number)%3A%20Promise%3CTableMap%5BKey%5D%20%7C%20null%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20result%20%3D%20row('person'%2C%201)), which demonstrates that the `result` if of type `Promise<Table.person>`.

Comment: Thanks! It works nice. No, for this purpose I didn't need a namespace and I ended up simplifying your example a bit by defining the type directly in the `TableMap` and using `function row<Key extends keyof TableMap>`.